# 400 Bad Request on Post .Net Core API via Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to call a simple method with ajax as follow:

```
[Route("v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FooController : Controller
{   [HttpPost]
    public FooDTO Add(Foo Foo)
    {
       FooDTO  objFooDTO   = null;
     }
}

public class Foo 
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

Ajax request is as follow:

```
var obj = {
            "ID": 0,
            "Title": "Foo Bar"
        }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8001/v1/Foo",
        data: obj,
        async: false,
        dataType: "Json",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        cache: false,
        success: function (resp) {

        },
        error: function (e) {

        }
    });
```

Its working fine with `POSTMAN` but when I try to hit via ajax error is `400` Bad request `The input is not valid`. Is there anything which I am missing ? `jquery` version is `1.12.0`.

Comment: Can you post a postman screenshot with url visible? Shouldn't your url in ajax be: url: "http://localhost:8001/v1/Foo/Add"?

Comment: @Nemanja Todorovic No it should not be /Add I have set a route which is `[Route("v1/[controller]")]`

Comment: @Nemanja Todorovic same url I am calling from postman

Comment: You haven't decorated the `Add` method with `HttpPostAttribute`.

Comment: @Chris Pickford Sorry I missed it while posting a question. Just updated.

Comment: Shouldn't this `url: "http://localhost:8001/v1/Foo"` be `url: "http://localhost:8001/v1/Foo/Add"`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh No it should not be /Add. I have set a route. which is `[Route("v1/[controller]")]`

Comment: you can also see the jquery code generated by postman, there you might see a clue on what is wrong

Comment: @Firdaus Kamaruddin already compared.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: @crgolden tried but no gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `contentType` property supposed to be `application/json` as you are passing on an object but not form data.

Also, you should serialize data object with `JSON.Stringify` method so that the javascript object will be converted to json.

Comment: Have you tried serializing the data object with json.stringify method in your ajax call?

Comment: It worked with `application/json` and `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @Afnan, modified. Thanks.